# NSOperation with completition block

Tags: ios, optimization, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have some image processing that take much time and resources, so i use [`NSOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) + [`NSOperatioQueue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperationQueue) + delegate for callBack. and all work.

now i want to use blocks because its much elegant and simple to use in a tableView for example.

what i need to do is just like [`AFJSONRequestOperation`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
 } failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

in this example i don't see any operationQueue ! how can i do the same?

```
    [ImageManagerOperation modifyImage:(UIImage*)image completitionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *modifiedImage))complete];
```

where ImageManagerOperation is an NSOperation.

I know that i can set a Completion Block, but i still need to add the operation in a queue.

i want to minimize the line number in my code (if possible :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the code in an `NSOperation` is synchronous.  The `NSOperationQueue` provides the threads needed to run the code in the background.  So you add your operation to a queue and the queue then calls `start` on your operation on a background thread.

`AFJSONRequestOperation` is a special type of `NSOperation` called `concurrent`, this means the operation already provides it's own background threads internally.  In some circumstances you may call the `start` method of a `concurrent` operation outside of a queue. Because the operation already provides it's own background threads it would still run in the background.  In this case `start` might be called directly just to minimise the code shown in the example.

Normally you would still add `concurrent` operations to an `NSOperationQueue` because you want to take advantage of the other things the queue provides such as managing `dependancies` and the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

So just create yourself an `NSOperationQueue` and add your operation to it.  You wont need to call `start` the queue will do this for you.

Comment: thank you, so in the end i have to create my own queue, i this for a tableView this will be much effort, so i do that with GCD and that work fine, and i'm really

Comment: thank you, so in the end i have to create my own queue, to adapt this for a tableView will be much effort, so i do that with GCD and that work fine (i think GCD use operation right ?). you answer my question so i accept it thank you :)

Comment: No, NSOperation uses GCD not the other way round.  It sounds like you need a queue so you can limit the amount of work you do from your table view.  Im assuming you are doing work for each cell while scrolling?  If some one scrolls a lot you may start too much work. Using a queue helps limit this and also let's you cancel tasks that may have been started for a cell but are no longer needed because the user has scrolled away.  There is a WWDC (I think 2012) session that discusses this in depth.  You should look for this video if this is what you are doing too.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i'm doing, i call that 'GCD' block in the 'willdisplaycell' method,but i think you are right, i have to optimize my cause because the app will be a messaging application, so allot of cells can be displayed thank you, i'll use a client account to access this video session :) thank you.