# Use Blocks with NSOperation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is a continuation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435920/nsoperation-with-completition-block).
I have a problem with blocks with an NSOperation, my application crash in the `completionblock`.

i think that the problem is a retain cycle (i have a warning : `Capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle`), i try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a) (see the code above), the warning is gone but the app still crash.

the application is a simple tableView. the operation apply some modification in the passed image.

this is the first time i create and use block myself, thank you to give me some fundamental explication

***code:***

**TableViewController.m:**

in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
   [[ImageManager sharedManager] modifyImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"] completionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {        
    [cell.imageView setImage:image];
}];
```

**ImageManager.h:**

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 @interface ImageManager : NSObject
 @property(nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *imageOperationQueu;

 -(void) modifyImage:(UIImage*)image completionBlock:(void(^)(UIImage *image,NSError *error)) completBlock;

 + (id) sharedManager;

 @end
```

**ImageManager.m:**

```
#import "ImageManager.h"
#import "ImageOperations.h"

static ImageManager *MySharedManager = nil;

@implementation ImageManager

@synthesize imageOperationQueu;

+ (id)sharedManager
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    if (MySharedManager == nil) MySharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return MySharedManager;
}

- (NSOperationQueue *)imageOperationQueu
{
   if (!imageOperationQueu)
 {
    imageOperationQueu = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [imageOperationQueu setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];
    imageOperationQueu.name = @"imageOperationQueu";
 }
return imageOperationQueu;
}

-(void) modifyImage:(UIImage*)image completionBlock:(void(^)(UIImage *image,NSError *error)) completBlock
{
 ImageOperations *op = [[ImageOperations alloc]initWithImage:image WithCompletionBlock:completBlock];
[self.imageOperationQueu addOperation:op];
}
@end
```

**ImageOperations.h:**

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(UIImage *image,NSError *error);

 @interface ImageOperations : NSOperation

 @property(nonatomic, weak) CompletionBlock completBlock;
 @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageToTransform;

 -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image WithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock) block;
 @end
```

**ImageOperations.m:**

```
 #import "ImageOperations.h"

 @implementation ImageOperations
 @synthesize imageToTransform;
 @synthesize completBlock;

 -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image WithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock) block
 {
  if (self = [super init])
  {
    NSLog(@"initWithImage");
    self.imageToTransform = image;
    [self setCompletBlock:block];
  }
 return self;
}

- (void)main
{
  @autoreleasepool
{        
    UIImage *img = [self setRoundedImage:self.imageToTransform];

    __weak ImageOperations *imgOp = self;

    [imgOp setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"setCompletionBlock");
        imgOp.completBlock(img,nil);
    }];
}
}

-(UIImage*)setRoundedImage:(UIImage*)image
{
// ..
}

@end
```

Comment: A retain cycle won't cause your app to crash. Premature deallocation will.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your completion block and see if `cell` is valid when you're trying to use it. Since it's in a block, it is async and `cell` may or may not be valid at that time. You might want to declare cell with __block (`__block UITableViewCell *cell`)

Comment: First of all: Any stacktrace or console output when the crash occurs?

Comment: #H2CO3, yes it's right but much leak will cause a crash i think.
i modify my code to set completBlock in ImageOperations as strong, now it's work (really really slow, but this is an other problem), but i have again that warning and after i scroll the app crash.
#JaiGovindani, after my code modification, the modified images are displayed, so i don't think this is the problem.
#NickWeaver, no nothing in log or the debug navigator (in xcode)! i'm testing in a device.

Comment: @RedMak If you're wondering why it's slow, it's because you're calling  the completion block from the background queue, but your block is updating the UI. You should dispatch those calls back to the main queue, e.g. `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ ... }`

Comment: is there any guarantee that blocks will be called in the main thread ?
or have i to use into a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{} ?

Comment: @RedMak No, there is no guarantee it will be called from main thread. To the contrary, when you manually call the completion block, it will be called from whatever queue you ran it from. So you should use either `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)` or the `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ ... }];` to submit it back to the main queue (as a stylistic matter, when doing GCD I'll do the former, when doing `NSOperation` code, I'll use the latter, but either works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You have your block defined as a `weak` property. In the [Working With Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12) section of *Programming with Objective-C* guide they advise that you use `copy` instead. (Note, we're copying the block, not the objects it uses; you do have to be careful of strong references within that block, though.) The scope of block variables is surprisingly subtle. (See [Patterns to Avoid](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW6) in the *Block Programming Topics* guide for examples.) And calling a `block` that was released because it was `weak` can generate some unpredictable results. Use `copy`.
2. Your tableview has a subtle issue, which is what would happen if the cell had scrolled off by the time the completion block was invoked. The cell could have been reused for another row of your table. (As it turns out, corner rounding logic is probably fast enough that this problem is unlikely to manifest itself, but this is critical if you do slower operations such as downloading images or if the images were huge.) Anyway, instead of:

   ```
   [[ImageManager sharedManager] modifyImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"] completionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {        
       [cell.imageView setImage:image];
   }];
   ```

   you might want to call the `UITableView` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (not to be confused with the `UITableViewController` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

   ```
   [[ImageManager sharedManager] modifyImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"] completionBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {   
       if (error == nil)
       {     
           UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           // if cell has scrolled off screen, this will be `nil`, so let's check

           if (updateCell)
               [updateCell.imageView setImage:image];
       }
   }];
   ```
3. You might want to be sensitive to the fact that the `imageNamed` method, itself, can be slow with first retrieving an image. If all of the cells are returning the same `imageNamed`, this is not an issue, but if (a) using unique `imageNamed` files; and (b) if dealing with older, slower device, you might even want to push the `imageNamed` process into the background queue, too. On newer devices (or on the simulator), you'll never see the issue, but if you test on a old, slow device, you might see some stuttering in a fast tableview scroll (but because `imageNamed` caches, you'll only see this stuttering UI when image is first retrieved...if you're using the same image name for all of them, you might not see this.)
4. Your call to `completBlock` is being done in the background queue. Since you're doing UI updates, you might want to make sure to dispatch this back to the main queue:

   ```
   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
       // call the completBlock here
   }];
   ```

Comment: thank you, you give some points that i don't understand them before